# javac path setup windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, path

I'm trying to return to java programming on a new computer. I have JDK installed, but when I try to compile with javac it tells me:

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I understand this may mean I have to set up the path so that windows can find the compiler, but I have no idea how to do that (the oracle guide I found goes up to windows 7, but I have windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is very similar to Windows 7 in terms of setting up environment variables.

In Windows 10:

1. Click *This PC* (rather than *My Computer*).
2. From the left side of the *System* window, choose the *Advanced System Settings* link.
3. In the *System Properties* dialog box, click the *Advanced Tab* and then press the *Environment Variables...* button.
4. For javac, you will likely want to highlight your *Path* variable (under *System variables*), then *Edit* it and add an entry like *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk_x.x.x\bin* to the list (since the *bin* folder is where *javac.exe* typically resides).

Note that you will need to use the actual path to your JDK installation.